# LLVM Framework: load IR files, link libraries

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, llvm, jit, llvm-ir

I am writing a simple JIT compiler using LLVM framework.
There's some nontrivial functionality, so that its generation
became very complicated, as it uses a couple of dynamic libraries.
So my questions are following:

- Is there a way to load an LLVM IR source via llvm::Builder/any other class
- Is there a way to tell LLVM, that at runtime some dynamic library ought to be linked, before execution...

The first question is more insteresting, as I already know how to require linkage from C/C++ applications, so I can generate LLVM IR code via Clang, but it comes up to the first question asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, there is an llvm/linker... Who could think so?
:)